# jQuery events are only binding once

Tags: jquery, events, mouseover, mouseout

I have mouseover and mouseout events that I want to be binded all the time. i.e. if I mouseover an element, then mouseout, then mouseover, and so on, these event handlers should still trigger. How should I fix this? Right now they are only binding once....

```
    $welcome = $("#welcome");
    $welcomeClone = $("#welcome").clone();

    $welcome.mouseover(function() {
        $welcome.css("height","400px");
    });

    $welcome.mouseout(function() {
        $welcome.hide();
        $("#vertical-center").append($welcomeClone)
    });
```

Comment: You mean you're newly appended clone of `$welcome` doesnt have any events..

Comment: Ohhhhhh that makes sense. How should I fix that?

Comment: have a look at .bind() or .on() function's

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because each `mouseout` you hide the `$welcome` element - then append a clone of it to `#vertical-center` - that cloned element doesnt have the same event handlers. You should use event delegation:

```
$welcome = $("#welcome");
$welcomeClone = $("#welcome").clone();

$("#vertical-center").on("mouseover", "#welcome", function() {
    $(this).css("height", "400px");
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#vertical-center").append($welcomeClone)
});
```